# Mata in .ado files

Tags: stata

I'm currently writing a little Stata program in an .ado file. Within this .ado file I want to use Mata in order to use the optimize() functions. When I type `end` in order to exit MATA, the .ado file reads this as the end of the program (I think). How do I go about this? I'm really new to both Stata and Mata and especially the use of both of them simultaneously. Here's an example of my code:

```
program define test
args epv prev0 prev1 sample_size bin_prev rep

local prevdiff=`prev1'-`prev0'
local t=-log(1-`prev0')
local eventprob=`epv'/`sample_size'
local lambda_c=0.5
local lambda_0=1
local lambda_1=-log(1-`prev0'-`prevdiff')/`t'

mata
mata clear

void cens_func(todo, x, y, g, H)
{
y = "some function of x and the locals"
}

S = optimize_init()
optimize_init_evaluator(S, &cens_func())
optimize_init_which(S, "min")
optimize_init_params(S, 1)
temp=optimize(S)
st_local("lambda_c",strofreal(temp))

end

some Stata code here

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the Mata code in a separate block at the end.

Schematically,

```
program 

end 

mata: 

end
```

Also, don't use the program name `test`, which is the name of an official command.

Also, see

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#spell

for correct spellings Stata, Mata.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By doing this, will I be able to call the local `lambda_c` (which I find in the Mata code) within the Stata program even though the Mata code comes afterwards? Regarding the name `test`, it is just something I have used here, but thanks :)

Comment: Yes. The key point here is that this code just defines a program. The whole of a program needs to be defined before it can be run. What comes first is in fact immaterial, except for the problem you found that `end` needs to refer to the previous opener. That said, I don't understand what this program is going to do, but there is no point in defining `lambda_c` before the Mata function is called (no harm done either).

Comment: Thanks alot. This is really a great answer. So what you're saying is, that I don't need to define `lambda_c` anywhere, and that `st_local("lambda_c",strofreal(temp))` will create a local called `lambda_c` with the value given by `temp`? Just to be sure.

Comment: Correct: if your Mata function doesn't need to be given the value of `lambda_c` then Mata will happily create it in the calling program.