# Using Mata in .ado files - syntax error

Tags: stata

This question is in continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580571/mata-in-ado-files), but since it can be answered without knowledge of my previous question, I thought posting a new question was the way to do it (I'm sorry if this is not the case). In the previous question I was told that putting Mata code at the end of my .ado-file would make the local `var2` usable within the Stata code. A minimal example is the following:

```
program define hello
args var1
local sum_var=`var1'+`var2'
disp `sum_var'
end

mata
void cens_func(todo, x, y, g, H)
{
y = (x-1)^2
}

S = optimize_init()
optimize_init_evaluator(S, &cens_func())
optimize_init_which(S, "min")
optimize_init_params(S, 2)
temp=optimize(S)
st_local("var2",strofreal(temp))
end
```

which unfortunately does not run. I am getting an invalid syntax error. Running this in a .do-file with the Mata code first, causes no errors. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer back to my answer yesterday. Mata will create a new local, or change an existing local, but you can't *use* a local before it has been created. Nothing to do with Mata changes that.

On calling Mata from Stata, see `help m1_ado`.

Thus in your code, you would need a Mata call before you tried to use `var2` as your Mata function creates `var2`.

Comment: I completely follow your argument, that it has to be called. My problem is that, when looking at `help m1_ado`, it seems that what I want to call should be encapsuled in a `void functionname(..) { do something }`. But my Mata code is not a function of some variable, and it does not need to be given any input. I think I probably have to find some other way to do this problem, since I'm obviously not "getting" the way Mata works.

Comment: If so, you don't need the Stata program at all as you can just define a Mata function to use interactively. Many Stata users do that. However, you have given your function arguments and they must be supplied somehow. Otherwise, nothing will work whichever way you do it.

Comment: "However, you have given your function arguments and they must be supplied somehow." What function do you mean? The function `cens_func` is defined as it should according to the `mf_optimize` manual. And it works fine if you run the Mata code seperately in Stata.

Comment: As you can get it to work, you must understand what I mean, just not the way I worded it.

Comment: It seems like we're talking a bit past each other. I'll leave it at this, and thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, you don't define `var2` so that alone should cause the
first assignment of a `local` to fail as Stata will see a hanging plus
sign.

There is any case no chance of this working if only because the Mata
function is never called by the Stata code.

Generally, reports such as "does not run" or even "syntax error" are not
really informative as they give no real clue to others on what is
happening. Stata is not at fault here as it provides debugging tools so
that with `set trace on` you can see which line is failing.

Running this as a do-file just defines a program; it doesn't certify that
it is legal or even correct.

On this evidence, you should try writing some simpler programs before
you have a realistic prospect of getting this to work. Even copying some
of the example programs from the manual will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is a fairly simple program, and suspect that you don't follow my question. All I want is to be able to do some manipulation within a Mata enviroment, such as maximizing/minimizing a certain function, and output that as a `local` to be used in the Stata enviroment. The Mata code from above runs perfectly fine, and is simply just a way of minimizing the function (x-1)^2.

Comment: Perhaps so, but your Mata code isn't linked to your Stata code. Your question I understood to be why the program does not work and I gave hints on why that is. I imagine that you are misunderstanding the way that Stata and Mata work together. In a program such as you have written the Mata code will not be used if it is not called by the Stata code. As before, you can define any number of Mata functions in a program file, but if they are not called nothing will happen. In particular, the Mata code will _only_ define a local such as `var2` if it is called.

Answer (score 1):

I do this quite a bit:

```
program define... 
  tempvar var2
  gen `var2' = <<whatever>>
  mata: myroutine("`var2'")
end

mata:
void myroutine(string scalar inputvar)
{
  real vector v
  st_view(v,.,inputvar)
  <<use v somehow>>
}
end
```

You call also use `st_store` to write a new Stata variable. My code just reads it into Mata.